# Bootstrap selectpicker gives error when wrapped inside "$(document).ready(function () {"

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have encountered many issues trying to put on same page Bootstrap-Selectpicker, 
Bootstrap-Datetimepicker, Bootstrap-Table, Bootstrap Modal form...

So I decided doing thing from scratch.  I have following code giving me an error:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
       style: 'btn-info',
       size: 4
   });
});
```

```html
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title>Untitled 1</title>

    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.9.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="~/Scripts/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> @**** Version de JQUERY utilisée **** *@
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.9.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>  
</head>

<body>
    <select class="selectpicker">
        <option>Mustard</option>
        <option>Ketchup</option>
        <option>Relish</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

[image]

But when my script is put this way it does not give any error.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
...
});

$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    style: 'btn-info',
     size: 4
});
```

I think my subsequent issues are derived from this. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your DOM is loading before the external dependencies for bootstrap-select are loaded in (since you're using an external link to the files).

Try this instead:

```
$(window).load(function() { 

   // bootstrap-select code

})
```

Comment: Hi, that leads the error below:

jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function
    at w.fn.init.w.fn.load (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at ListeDemandeurs?Length=6:651